# Convert a set of numbers into a word

Tags: python-2.7

I need to convert a given string of numbers to the word those numbers correspond to. For example:

```
>>>number_to_word ('222 2 333 33')
'CAFE'
```

The numbers work like they do on a cell phone, you hit once on the second button and you get an 'A', you hit twice and you get an 'B', etc. Let's say I want the letter 'E', I'd have to press the third button twice. 
I would like to have some help trying to understand the easiest way to do this function. I have thought on creating a dictionary with the key being the letter and the value being the number, like this:

```
dic={'A':'2', 'B':'22', 'C':'222', 'D':'3', 'E':'33',etc...}
```

And then using a 'for' cycle to read all the numbers the in the string, but I do not know how to start.

Comment: Which part don't you know: how to make the dictionary (you *seem* to know that) or breaking a string into words (you can't have looked too hard to find out how to do that), or something else?

Comment: If you want to go from the numbers to the word, why not have the keys be the things like `'222'` and the values the letters?

Comment: I know how to make the dictionary, what I don't know is how to make the 'for' cycle run through the dic and add the letters to the empty string:' ' ( which will be the final word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse your dictionary:

```
def number_to_word(number):
    dic = {'2': 'A', '22': 'B', '222': 'C', '3': 'D', '33': 'E', '333': 'F'}
    return ''.join(dic[n] for n in number.split())

>>> number_to_word('222 2 333 33')
'CAFE'
```

Let's start inside out. `number.split()` splits the text with your number at white space characters:

```
>>> number = '222 2 333 33'
>>> number.split()
['222', '2', '333', '33']
```

We use a generator expression (`(dic[n] for n in number.split())`) to find the letter for each number. Here is a list comprehension that does nearly the same but also shows the result as a list:

```
>>> [dic[n] for n in number.split()]
['C', 'A', 'F', 'E']
```

This lets `n` run through all elements in the list with the numbers and uses `n` as the key in the dictionary `dic` to get the corresponding letter.

Finally, we use the method `join()` with an empty string as spectator to turn the list into a string:

```
>>> ''.join([dic[n] for n in number.split()])
'CAFE'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But can you extend in more code the return line please? I'm kinda new to python so I don't fully understand your code all in one line.

Comment: I see now, but what if I need to make the programm be able to read the same letter if the input is '2' ( the letter is 'A') or the input it's '2222'(the letter is still 'A')? Like when it get's to end of the amount of letters that number can have, it "restarts" all over. For example the letter 'A', can be printed if the input is '2' ,'2222','2222222',etc.

Comment: This looks like a new question to me. Just ask a another one and explain in detail what you have done so far and what you want, i.e. create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can't ask another question since I already asked this one, I have to wait a day or so, I'll try myself and start another question when I can, thank you :)